# TransferSpreadsheet acImport defaulting to documents folder - Run-time error 3011 (Access VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport isn't working for me currently.  I am trying to import .xlsx files and I am using the wildcard (*) to complete the file name.  When I use a MsgBox, FullPath is correct, but when the TransferSpreadsheet runs, it says it can't find the file in C:\Users\Me\Documents (the default location).

```
Dim FPath As String
Dim FName As String
Dim FullPath As String
FPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Data\"
FName = "DataTable"
FullPath = Dir(FPath & FName & "*.xlsx")
If FullPath <> "" Then
     DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, TableName, FullPath, 1
     Else: MsgBox "Error - file not found"
End If
```

Why is it not looking in the place where I designate?  Is this error incorrect and it is indicating something else?

Comment: You don't specify anything for `FilePath`.

Comment: Can't use a wildcard in name of file to export to. Do you have Option Explicit in module header? You Dim FullPath but use FilePath for export filename.

Comment: Apologies - I've made the correction.

Comment: @June7 I've just added a Dir() around the definition of FullPath to account for this but it still won't work.  Does this point to a different issue than the one you've suggested?

Comment: Well, FullPath value has a wildcard. That won't work for specifying filename to save to. Why do you even use wildcard?

Comment: @June7 I'm using wildcard because the file name is something like DataTable_210513_164923.  The name is not consistent so I need a way of importing the file using only a keyword.

Comment: I stand corrected. Dir(something) returns name of first file that matches the pattern so the variable does not have wildcard. It is only the filename, not a full path.

Answer (score 1):

`Dir()` only returns a file *name* or nothing (empty string).  It does not return a full path.

```vb
Dim FPath As String
Dim FileName As String

FPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\Data\"

FileName = Dir(FPath & "DataTable*.xlsx")

If FileName <> "" Then
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, 10, TableName, FPath & FileName, 1
Else
    MsgBox "Error - file not found"
End If
```

Comment: That does not seem to be correct - when I add MsgBox FileName to my code it returns the full filepath.

Comment: That's not the documented behavior, and it's not what I see.  For example `? Dir("C:\Tester\*.xlsx")` in the Immediate pane gives me `Data.xlsx` and not `C:\Tester\Data.xlsx`

Comment: I get same behavior as @TimWilliams describes.

Comment: My mistake, I was referencing the wrong part of my code.